# Oracle, Subsonic 3 and TableSpaceName

Tags: oracle, subsonic3

When I go to run the t4 templates, the result comes out *"Compiling transformation: The name 'TableSpaceName' does not exist in the current context"* -- any ideas on this?  I thought it might be a namespace/reference issue, but it doesn't seem to be part of the ODP.

This is one of those "it has to be something stupid" ... why? I've got subsonic 2 to work with oracle on the same box, using the same server, same connection string so it has to be something I'm overlooking or not expecting.

I have downloaded [the oracle template provider example](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/File%3AOracleTemplateProviderExample.RAR) and I've hit github for the latest and greatest, trying various combinations of both with the results being the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your T4 template, check if you have imported the assembly that includes the missing 'TableSpaceName':

```
<#@ assembly name="[ABSOLUTE-PATH-TO-ASSEMBLY]\[ASSEMLBYNAME]" #>
```